# Tor permission error

Tags: help, debian

I am trying to run hidden services with tor. But when I start it just using `tor` I get this error:

> ... is not owned by this user (user, 1000) but by debian-tor (118). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user?

When I run it using `sudo tor`:

> ... is not owned by this user (root, 0) but by debian-tor (118). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user?

And when I try `sudo service tor start` it doesn't show any errors but it still doesn't works.

I also added `User debian-tor` to torrc. But than I get the error `Directory /root/.tor cannot be read: Permission denied` when I run it as root(`sudo tor`). And the error `Directory ... cannot be read: Permission denied` when I run it with `tor` or as service.

When I change the owner of the directory to root I can start it with `sudo tor` but still not with `sudo service tor start`, I also don't think it is save tor run it with the root user.

I am using Debian Jessie.
Does anyone know how I can fix this?
I want to run tor as a service.

**EDIT:** I installed centos and got the exact same error...

But i found out when I use `/var/lib/tor/` as directory it works!
But when I use `/var/lib/tor/hidden_service/` (With user _tor as owner) I still have an permission error. I tried to add `ReadWriteDirectories` to `tor.service` with `/var/lib/tor/hidden_service/` as directory. But that also doesn't work.

Comment: For your second example, have you edited anything to allow you to run as root? (I was under the impression that such a thing would be blocked due to safety concerns.) How did you install Tor in the first place? By downloading the bundle from the Tor site, or from a repository?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks I followed option 2 from this website. https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en When I start it as root it does say that i probably shouldn’t do it. But it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that tor was blocked by SElinux.
I disabled SElinux and everything was working.

Comment: You should not disable SElinux, it's a good thing! Do you need help in writing a ruleset for it?

Answer (score 4):

When you want to start via command line you need to do it as the correct user. As the message says it expects `debian-tor`. So call Tor in the following way:

```
sudo -u debian-tor tor
```

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but I want to run tor as a service.
I just tried this command and I get an permission error.

Comment: I was just stuck with this same problem, and this solution worked for me perfectly. I'd like to add to this that to see what user might be required for tor, one can do a search for users created using: `sudo lastlog` which will show a list of users. I would expect one to exist there that has _tor_ included in it. 

It might also be found using `sudo ls -la /var/run/` which should host the TOR folder, of whose permission would be the one you're looking for to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chown debian-tor:debian-tor /var/lib/tor/site/
sudo systemctl restart tor
```

fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

You're missing `DataDirectory /usr/tor/data` in your torrc. And make a `debian-tor` user you've mentioned in your setup have a `/bin/bash` shell and a home directory `/usr/tor` - it will solve your problem and help you to run pluggable transports without a problem. Do it like this from root :

```
mkdir -p /usr/tor/data
chown -R debian-tor:`id -g debian-tor` /usr/tor
usermod -d /usr/tor -s /bin/bash debian-tor
```

Comment: The `DataDirectory` should not live under `/usr`. Furthermore the OP uses a Debian-based system. So there is a high chance that `DataDirectory` is set correctly.

Comment: I've provided my working example, so it's no problem to set up his own data path, not like `/root/.tor` of course. And where it should be - tastes different

Comment: The FHS says otherwise.

Comment: @JensKubieziel don't forget, that there's a very handy things at hand in Linux, like [AppArmor](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/Main_Page), privilege separation and [CGroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups). Take a deep look, and you will understand, that there's nothing bad in residing a whole tor dir inside `/usr` **properly secured**

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin Please check out my edit. The hidden service is working with /var/lib/tor/ but not with other directories. Not even /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/

Comment: @user2735398 is there anything in `dmesg` and `/var/log/syslog` ?

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin No not anything usefull

Comment: @user2735398 If it's a message within syslog/dmesg - then it can be AppArmor or SELinux problem, but if it's not - try to compile Tor from Git. Recently I've helped via TeamViewer to one person who **actually had a fake tor.exe binary** - and it was very silent binary, no logs where they must be...